# Minimalist X11 tool for night light

Tags: x11, openbox, backlight

I'm running OpenBox on a Debian 10 Buster system and I'm looking for a simple minimalist command line tool to toggle night light (as in Ubuntu). Any suggestions?

Comment: [Redshift](https://packages.debian.org/buster/redshift)?

Comment: Are you asking about a tool to reduce blue light, to that it is easier to sleep (and easier on the eyes) after using computer?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor yes exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `xflux` from [f.lux](https://justgetflux.com) on my OpenBox desktop, it's a simple command line tool for X Window System with multiple monitor support. You can download it [here](https://justgetflux.com/linux.html).

Just download the archive, extract it and move the `xflux` binary file to a directory registered in your `$PATH`. Then add to you `~/.config/openbox/autostart` file the line

```
xflux -l latitude -g longitude
```

Depending on your location, the program will automatically adjust the light. You can also change the color with the `-k` flag.

Comment: What would be the difference if I add this line to my .xinitrc file?

Comment: Not much. The program will be launched by all X sessions instead of being launched only at OpenBox startup.